# Prove $ f(A1) \setminus f(A2) \subseteq f(A1 \setminus A2) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

here is my proof but it only works for functions that have an inverse:

[image]

Comment: Please put a little effort in and write up a post with MathJax. :) Its hard to read your work.

Comment: Still trying to get the hang of it

Comment: Heres a quick tutorial: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511662/proving-fc-setminus-fd-subseteq-fc-setminus-d-and-disproving-equality

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving $f(C) \setminus f(D) \subseteq f(C \setminus D)$ and disproving equality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511662/proving-fc-setminus-fd-subseteq-fc-setminus-d-and-disproving-equality)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can prove it by showing that all elements from $f(A1) - f(A2)$ belong to $f(A1 - A2)$. (Let me use the symbol $-$ for the exclusion of sets.)

Let's consider a $y \in f(A1) - f(A2)$. This implies two consequences:

- $y \in f(A1) \Rightarrow \exists x \in A1 \text{ s.t. } f(x) = y$.
- $y \not\in f(A2) \Rightarrow \forall x' \in A2,\: f(x') \not= y$.

Since $f(x) = y \not= f(x')$, we derive that $x \not= x'$ for any $x' \in A_2$. Therefore, $x \not\in A_2$.

In conclusion, $\exists x \in A1 - A2 \text{ s.t. } f(x) = y$, so $y \in f(A1 - A2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Or $f(A_1)\setminus f(A_2)\subset f(A_1\setminus A_2)\Leftrightarrow f(A_1)\subset f(A_1\setminus A_2)\cup f(A_2)=f((A_1\setminus A_2)\cup A_2)=f((A_1\cup A_2)\cap (A_2^{c} \cup A_2))=f(A_1\cup A_2)$ and $A_1\subset A_1\cup A_2$

Answer (score 1):

Claim $(\forall x)(x \in f(A1) \setminus f(A2) => x \in f(A1\setminus A2)$.

Let $x \in f(A1) \setminus f(A2)$.

$\Rightarrow
x \in f(A1)\land
x \notin f(A2)
$

$\Rightarrow
(\exists y \in A1)
f(y) = x
\land
(\not \exists z \in A2)
f(z) = x
$

$\Rightarrow 
(\exists y \in A1)
f(y) = x
\land 
(
\forall z \in A2)
f(z) \neq x
$

$
\Rightarrow
(\forall z \in A2)
(\exists y \in A1)
f(y) = x
\land{}
f(z) \neq x
$

$f$ a function $
\Rightarrow
(\forall z \in A2)
(\exists y \in A1) 
f(y) = x
\land
f(z) \neq x
\land
z \neq y
$

$
\Rightarrow
(\forall z \in A2)
(\exists y \in A1) 
f(y) = x
\land
f(z) \neq x
\land
(\forall z \in A2)
z \neq y
$

$
\Rightarrow
(\exists y \in A1)
f(y) = x
\land
y \notin A2
$

$
\Rightarrow
(\exists y)
y \in A1
\land
y \notin A2
\land
f(y) = x
$

$
\Rightarrow
(\exists y \in A1 \setminus A2)
f(y) = x
$

$
\Rightarrow
x \in f(A1 \setminus A2)
$